# ArrayList get by Object

Tags: java

I have `Person` class and `List<Person>` list, I have added a equals method into Person Bean ,

in that case `ArrayList` `contains` method can be used properly, but it returns boolean value,
is there a way of to get Value from `ArrayList` without for-loop like usage of `contains()` method.

Comment: `ArrayList.indexOf` then `ArrayList.get` ?

Comment: this makes no sense to me but maybe you can combine ```get(index)``` and ```indexOf(object)```

Comment: If processing time is of concern, I'm not completely sure if `indexOf` iterates under the hood. You could always use a `Map`, specifying the type as the key and value. But why would you wanna use a value to get that same value from a list?

Comment: downvote is not matter, thanks @Eran for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list.indexOf(person)` to get the index of the Person you are looking for.

```
List<Person> list = ...
Person person = ...
int index = list.indexOf(person);
if (index >= 0) {
    Person p = list.get(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Person p = list.get(list.indexOf(personYouAreLookingFor));
```

Please consider that indexOf() searches for the first occurrence of a object. Only first one would be retrieved.